# UICollectionView cellForItemAt not called after InsertItems(at:) - How to preload next cell?

Tags: swift, webview, collectionview

I'm working on a horizontal UICollectionView with full screen cells.

Cells have WKWebview inside, which loads next cell's url.

When the next url loaded, the new cell is inserted.

```
extension ViewController {
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        guard let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: WebCell.reuseId, for: indexPath) as? WebCell else { fatalError("Unexpected indexPath") } 

        cell.configure()
        cell.startLoadingURL(urls[indexPath.item])

        return cell
    }
}
```

```
extension ViewController: WebCellDelegate {
    func onNextURLLoaded(_ sender: WebCell, nextUrl: URL) {
        ...
        urls.append(nextUrl)
        horizontalCollectionView.performBatchUpdates({
            horizontalCollectionView.insertItems(at: [IndexPath(item: urls.count-1, section: 0)])
        }, completion: nil)

    }
}
```

What I want to do is - rendering next cell in advance.

The problem is - cellForItemAt method is not called after insertItems(at:).

But when I reduce cells' sizes so that next cell being visible, then cellForItemAt method is called and renders the next cell.

I want to preload next cell without reducing cell's size.
Is there any solutions?

Answer (score 0):

you can use `willDisplay cell` method

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, willDisplay cell: UICollectionViewCell, forItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    <#code#>
}
```